# Damaged Downloaded Zip Files

Tags: php, zip

i've made a PHP form which contains an input[type=file] that only accepts zip format files.
the zip file successfully uploads when the form is submitted.
i have also created a download link for admin to download the file which has uploaded by the user.
the problem is when the file is downloaded it has this error with it => "the archive is either in unknown format or damaged"

i would be thankful if you help me

here is my code :

```
if (!empty($_FILES)){
    foreach ($_FILES as $key=>$file){

        $fileName = $file['name'];
        $fileTmp = $file['tmp_name'];

        $fileExt = explode(".",$fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        $allowed = ['zip'];
        if (in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed)){
            $newFileName = $requestId."-".$key."-".$_SESSION['user_id']."-planForm".".".$fileActualExt;
            $newFileLocation = "../mehrdadfit/img/plan-form/$newFileName";
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmp,$newFileLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remember we are not clairvoyant. There is only enough information here for use to commiserate

Comment: Start by checking that the original Zip file is valid. Then check the file when it has been uploaded to the server, is it still valid zip file? Then you will have an idea where if anywhere the corruption is being created

Comment: Is the file being stored in the database or on the file system?

Comment: Are you creating the file using PHP or is someone else (the user) creating the zip file

Comment: Are you sure its a zip file and not some other format of compression that was used

Comment: I think you better to show your upload code

Comment: thank you all for your answers. i thought maybe my problem is not related to my code and that's why i didn't upload it. but if you need to see my codes, i'm gonna edit the post and upload it

Comment: the file stores in a file system(it is on my localhost now)

Comment: the user creates the zip file and then upload it to the form

Comment: Did you build the .zip file you are testing this code with or is someone else being the user in this senario

Comment: I created the zip file for test.i edited my post by the way so you can see how i store the file in file system